# Collection View cell height reverting back to default size

Tags: swift

I have 3 different collectionViewCells all which should be different sizes, I've set them all to have a custom size but the cell size reverts back to the default size set by the collectionView during runtime. I've tried this within my `cellForIndexPath`

```
   cell.frame = CGRectMake(cell.frame.origin.x, cell.frame.origin.y, cell.frame.size.width, 200)
```

Comment: Can you show code cellforrowatindexpath and size for cell at index path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`collectionView(_:cellForItemAtIndexPath:)` is a member of `UICollectionViewDataSource` which means it deals with data population of the cell, not visual presentation. The Apple documentation on this method states: "You do not need to set the location of the cell inside the collection view’s bounds. The collection view sets the location of each cell automatically using the layout attributes provided by its layout object." Most likely you're setting the frame and the layout object is overriding that value.

What you're looking for is `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout`s `collectionView(_:layout:sizeForItemAtIndexPath:)` method. Here you can specify the frame size of individual cells. If you want to get really crazy, you can even write your own layout.